# Where is the civicrm.settings.php file on Wordpress 4.95 with CiviCRM 5.1.x

Tags: wordpress, civicrm.settings.php

I'm having trouble with the resource url in a new implementation of wordpress 4.95 and civi 5.1

It is greyed out when listing it via admin/ Settings - Resource URLs

A popup tells me that "Some fields are loaded as 'readonly' as they have been set (overridden) in civicrm.settings.php."

There is no longer a civicrm.settings.php file in /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm

There is a folder called settings and a lot of stuff under that.

Whats all this about? Documentation doesn't help much with this.. just keeps referring me to the non existent civicrm.settings.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm path is for CiviCRM versions older than 4.7.  For a new install you should find it under /wp-content/uploads/civicrm